# Redirect Web Page Requests to a Default Sub Folder

Tags: asp.net, redirect, webserver, ultidev

I am using UltiDev Web Server Pro and have all my aspx files are located in a sub folder 'WebForms'.

I want to be able to default all requests for pages to this folder such that they can just type: 
`http://myserver/somepage.aspx` instead of

`http://myserver/WebForms/somepage.aspx`.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

Here is the VB.NET version of the solution below including a check for case sensitivity:

```
If Not HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.ToUpper.Contains("/WEBFORMS/") Then
    Context.RewritePath("/WebForms" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Path, False)
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Global.asax` and the `Application_BeginRequest` to `RewritePath` to the final destination and still have the link without the **WebForm** path.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if(!HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.Contain("/WebForms/"))
       RewritePath("/WebForms" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Path, false);  
}
```

Comment: Lovely solutions - In thought I would have to do this on the web server. I made a slight ammendment to check case sensitivity but otherwise great.